Tangent space to the zero set of a Killing field
I am reading Peter Petersen's Riemannian Geometry 3rd edition. I am stuck in the proof of Theorem 8.1.5.
The zero set $S$ of a Killing field $X$ is precisely the intersection of the fixed points of flow $F^t$ of $X$. Since for a Killing field, the flows are isometries, the tangent space for the zero set, $T_p S$ is the set of vectors fixed by $\mathrm{D}F^t|_p$, for all $t$.
The claim given in text reads $ T_p S = \ker (\nabla X)|p $. Essentially what this means is $ \mathrm{D}F^t (v) = v ~\forall t \iff \nabla_vX = 0 $. I am unable to prove this.
Usually, a flow is a property that comes from smoothness of a manifold, whereas connection comes from Riemannian metric, so generally, these two are not related. But for Killing fields, the flows are necessarily isometries, so any method we use to relate these two must use some property of Killing field. This is as far as I've gotten.

These properties lead to two important general results about Killing fields.

$\textbf{Theorem 8.1.5.}$ The zero set of a Killing field is a disjoint union of totally geodesic submanifolds each of even codimension.

Proof. The flow generated by a Killing field $X$ on $(M, g)$ acts by isometries so we know from proposition 5.6.5 that the fixed point set of these isometries is a union of totally geodesic submanifolds. We next observe that the fixed point set of all of these isometries is precisely the set of points where the Killing field vanishes. Finally, assume that $X|_p = 0$ and let $V = \ker (\nabla X)_p$. Then $V$ is the Zariski tangent space to the zero set and hence also the tangent space as in the proof of proposition 5.6.5. Thus $w \mapsto \nabla_w X$ is an isomorphism on $V^\perp$. As it is also a skew-symmetric map, it follows that $V^\perp$ is even-dimensional. $\qquad \square$


Assume that $\mathrm{D} F^t(v)=v \forall t$. Let $Y$be a vector field such that $Y(p)=v$. Since $p\in S$, we have by assumption
$$[Y,X](p)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\left([DF^t -Id](Y(p))\right)=0.$$
In addition as the metric is symmetric we have
$$[X,Y]=\nabla_{X}Y-\nabla_Y X.$$
Observe that $\nabla_X Y (p)=0$ by linearity of the connection. Thus,
$$[Y,X](p)=0\implies \nabla_Y X (p)=0. $$
I will let you fill out the details for the other direction. You will need to show that
$$[Y,X](p)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\left([DF^t -Id](Y(p))\right)=0.$$
So,
$$\frac{d}{dt}DF^t(Y(p))|_{t=0}=0.$$
Then you will need to use the identity for flows $DF^{t+s}=DF^{t}\circ DF^{s}$ to show that
$$\frac{d}{dt}DF^t(Y(p))|_{t=s}=0\qquad \forall s\in \mathbb{R}. $$
The result will now follow

Thank you @Elad. This works.
